# what is the range of index values for a leaf node in a heap data structure which is represented as a binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

If I have n elements in the heap then why does the index of leaf nodes ranges from index ⌊n/2⌋+1 to index n ? 
I tried thinking that the last node whose index is n will have the parent present at index ⌊n/2⌋ but then confusion is whether the parent is in left-subtree or right-subtree so that I can realize that in general whether a particular level is filled fully or not ?

Comment: Binary heaps are usually stored in arrays, the child nodes for a node at index i are at 2i and 2i+1 (for arrays starting at 1) parent nodes are at floor(i/2). For perfect binary heaps ((n+1)%2 == 0) all the leafs nodes are stored from n/2 + 1 to n, otherwise this isn't the case and the leaves are stored from 2^h to n where h is the height defined as floor(log2(n))